# SSIS packages deployed on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have deployed SSIS packages on SQL Server 2016 and these packages use tables in SQL Server 2008. Can I work on tables that are in SQL Server 2008 using SQL Server 2016?

Comment: What happens when you try?   Do you get an error?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, SSIS for SQL Server 2016 can select/insert/update/delete tables on a SQL Server 2008 instance.